# Splitting a string into integers

Tags: c, string

For my first task I am using `fgets()` to read a string from `stdin`. So I input `1234567890` on the terminal and it stores the string into a variable called `str`. Now I want to split the digits up and perform addition. In this case the sum would be `55` since `1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+0 = 55`.

How can I do that?

My code so far

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(void){

char str[100];

printf("Please enter the 10 digit number \n");
fgets(str, 10, stdin);

//Separate the digits


//calculate their sum
int sum =..............

//print out the sum
printf("the sum of the digits is: %s", sum);

return(0);
}
```

Comment: Initialize a 'sum' var to 0.  Iterate the string until the end.  Convert each ASCII char into an int.  Add it to the 'sum' var.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are sure the string will contain digits, subtract each character from `'0'` to get their numeric value.

```
int sum = 0;
fgets(str, sizeof str, stdin);
char *s = &str;
while(*s != '\0') {
    sum += *(s++) - '0';
}

printf("the sum of the digits is: %d", sum);
```

Answer (score 5):

**Approach 1:**

If you know for sure that you're counting for *single digit integer*, you can use

- array indexing to read the *digit-by-digit* value from the input string.
- convert the `char` value to corresponding `int` as per the required encoding (mostly, [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/)).
- define one `int` variable , say `res` to hold the sum. perform the addition and store the result to `sum`.
- loop untill terminating null is reached.
- print out the `sum` using `%d` format specifier.

**Approach 2:**

Alternatively, you can do something like (again assuming,*single digit integer*)

- Convert the whole *string* to integer using `strtol()`. You **must** check for the errors in that case.
- define one `int` variable , say `res` to hold the sum.
- perform modulo `10` (`%`0`) on the converted interger value to take out the last digit. add and store that in`res`
- divide converted interger value by `10` (`p /= 10`).
- continue to step 2 untill the result is `0`.
- when the converted interger value becomes `0`, print the `res`.

---

<sup>P.S - Just FYI, usual way of *splitting* a string based on some delimiter is to use [`strtok()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok).</sup>

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure that you read only digits by using `scanf`, like this:

```
char str[11]; // 10 digits plus \0 terminator
printf("Please enter the 10 digit number \n");
scanf("%10[0-9]", str);
```

Now you can go through the digits one by one by indexing into `str`, and subtracting the code of digit zero, like this:

```
int nextDigit = str[i] - '0';
```

This should be enough information for you to complete the solution by adding a `for` loop around it. Make sure that you print `sum` using `%d`, not `%s` like you did in your code sample.

Comment: I don't think we should lead people astray into bad programming practice, by telling them to prefer scanf instead of fgets.

Comment: @Lundin In this particular situation `scanf` provides a demonstrably superior alternative to `fscanf` in every single respect you could name, while staying equally safe. Sure, it provides more venues for abuse, but it has perfectly safe uses which every practitioner must learn.