# Converting double < - > char

Tags: c, list, stack, converters

I need to create a calculator, for that I have to separte the `operands (numbers)` and the `operators (+Sum, *Mult, -Sub, ^Expo)` on different *stacks/lists*

I need to save each of them on a  stack (wich is a *list*).
What I can't do is, how am I supposed to convert the character "+" into double then get it back from double to character ?  Or is there an easier way to do so ? I tried to print this:

```
char c = "+";
double d = c; //Now d = -23.00
printf("Plus: %c\n", d); //Prints an unknown character "?".
```

How could I reach where I need ?

Comment: eh? why you need a `double` there?

Comment: @SouravGhosh My stack/list has a double type and a pointer to the next element. Can't change this =\

Comment: Use a stack of tagged unions instead of shoehorning a char in a double!

Comment: `char c = "+";` is illegal; you mean `char c = '+';`. Assuming you fix that, `double d = c;` should set `d` to `43`, the ASCII code for the `'+'` character. You can't print a `double` value using `%c`; you'll get garbage at best.

Comment: This is wrong `char c = "+";`, what is being stored in the `double` is wrong, you mean `char c = '+'; printf("Plus: %c\n", c);`?

Comment: A typical stack-based calculator would not push the operators onto the stack. On reading an operator it would pop the operands from the stack, apply the operation, and push the result. Why do you want to push the operators onto a stack? Once you've done that, how will you associated the operators with their operands?

Comment: not a duplicate but can get some idea [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29235069/2173917)

Comment: @tux3 Could you give me some example, please ? First time working with `Union`

Comment: @PlayHardGoPro Something like `struct stackme{int type; union{double value;char op;};};` Or just remove the union, it won't save much anyways. Or better yet, do what @KeithThompson said if you can.

Answer (score 0):

If `d` is of type `double` correct output for it is `printf("Plus: %lf\n", d);` or `printf("Plus: %lg\n", d);` or `printf("Plus: %le\n", d);`, but not `printf("Plus: %c\n", d);`, because `%c` means "output of char data".

In C language `"+"` is not a character, it is a literal of type `char *` that represent string (formally it is a pointer).

when you use `=` (assignment operator) for different data types, some data transformation take place (such as data type promotion), but these transformation are not always useful. So, in you example, as I understand, you want to store operations as characters `'+'`, `'-'`, `'*'`, etc., and data as `double` values. In that case, you do not need transformation `char` to `double` at all. The only thing you need is a designing data structure for storing data and operations together but in different datatypes.

For example, as you wrote "different stacks/lists" can be used for data and operators... DIFFERENT!!!